# Entity Framework 6.3 in .NET6

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, .net-6.0

I'm having a problem using EF 6 (not EF Core) with .NET 6 everything works fine except when I try to add a migration.

I get the following error:

```
The type initializer for 'System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrationsConfiguration`1' threw an exception.
 ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig' threw an exception.
 ---> System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (0x80131040)
```

What could be the cause of this?

Comment: Although .NET 6 is .NET Core and EF Core is a more natural fit, EF 6 nevertheless should still work, as it's advertised as compatible -- if nothing else it's advertised to work with .NET Standard 2.1, which .NET 6 implements. At the same time, though, I expect any incompatibilities that do crop up for this combination to not actually be addressed. The fact that EF hasn't seen any releases for almost two years now (while EF Core is in active development) is a sign of where the priorities lie. If you haven't migrated yet, now would be a good time to start.

Comment: System.Runtime v6.0.0.0 is part of .NET 6.0.  Look in the build directory of your project, there's probably a copy of System.Runtime.dll there with the wrong version.  Deleting it is a workaround, but you probably should find out how it got there.

Comment: @HansPassant I'm using EF 6.3 and for some reason updating to EF 6.4.4 solved this problem. Although I don't exactly get why as both seem to be compatible with netstandard2.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For other people still wanting to use EF 6.3 with .NET Core for legacy reasons.

Add this to the project containing your **Configuration** file.

```
<PropertyGroup>
 <GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles>True</GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles>
</PropertyGroup>
```

You should now be able to execute ef commands.

Comment: Are you referring to the Web.Config file? This was deprecated I thought with .NET Core

Comment: @codedude no csproj